# How do I rewrite this SQL query in LINQ format?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a sql query that returns the surrounding rows for a given ID. So lets say I'm looking to find 3 rows for a given MediaID of 8000. (Previous Row, Current Row, Next Row).

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to achieve those results but here's my query anyway:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Media WHERE MediaTypeID = 1 and MediaID < 8000 order by MediaID DESC
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Media WHERE MediaID = 8000
    UNION 
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Media WHERE MediaTypeID = 1 and MediaID > 8000
) AS TBL
ORDER BY TBL.MediaID
```

I'm importing this query into a C# web application and would like to convert the query over to LINQ format. I'm struggling a bit with this. I think im close.

Here's my LINQ code:

```
//Get Prev record, current record, next record
var Results = (from m in DB.Media where m.MediaTypeID == 1 && m.MediaID < 8000 orderby m.MediaID descending select m).Take(1).Union(
from m in DB.Media where m.MediaID == 8000 select m).Union(
from m in DB.Media where m.MediaTypeID == 1 && m.MediaID > 8000 select m).Take(1);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look really close. I think you need an additional set of parentheses around the final statement your "union"ing (so that the `Take(1)` only applies to that last statement and not the entire unioned LINQ statement up to that point) and a final `OrderBy`:

```
var Results = (from m in DB.Media
               where m.MediaTypeID == 1
                  && m.MediaID < 8000
               orderby m.MediaID descending select m).Take(1)

            .Union(
               from m in DB.Media
               where m.MediaID == 8000
               select m)

            .Union(
               (from m in DB.Media
                where m.MediaTypeID == 1
                   && m.MediaID > 8000
                select m).Take(1))

            .OrderBy(m => m.MediaID);
```

Consider breaking this up into separate lines for clarity:

```
var lessThan8000 = (from m in DB.Media
                    where m.MediaTypeID == 1
                       && m.MediaID < 8000
                    orderby m.MediaID descending select m).Take(1);

var equalTo8000 = (from m in DB.Media
                   where m.MediaID == 8000
                   select m);

var greaterThan8000 = (from m in DB.Media
                       where m.MediaTypeID == 1
                          && m.MediaID > 8000
                       select m).Take(1));

var Results = lessThan8000.Union(equalTo8000)
                          .Union(greaterThan8000)
                          .OrderBy(m => m.MediaId);
```

Comment: Thanks Grant. Worked like a charm!